# Como faço um SELECT depois um INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-insert

Como faço um `SELECT` e se voltar mais de 1 registro faz o `UPDATE` e se voltar 0 registros faz o `INSERT`?

Olha como eu fiz aqui só que não ta dando certo:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $conexao->prepare("SELECT id_mark, id_user FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id AND id_user=:idLogged");
    $query->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

    if($result->rowCount() >= 1){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Erro!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar sua avaliação.
        </div>';
    }
    if($result->rowCount() == 0){

        $comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));

        $insert = "INSERT into tb_comment (id_mark, id_user, comment, up_c, down_c, rate, active) VALUES (:post_id, :idLogged, :comment, 0, 0, :star, NOW())";

            $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            if($result->rowCount() == 0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Sucesso!</strong> avaliação cadastrada.
                </div>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar a avaliação.
                </div>';
            }
    }
}//if
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: @bigown N apareceu nenhum erro de PHP, só que não tenho nenhum registro e está aparecendo a mensagem de Erro ao cadastrar

Comment: Tem dois erros ao cadastrar, qual deles?

Comment: O erro do 'if($result->rowCount() >= 1){'

Comment: não tem lógica as estruturas condicionais e também uso errôneo do rowCount() no insert.

Comment: O erro deve ser do SQL, mande imprimi-lo para ver o que é. Será chave duplicada? De qualquer forma esta lógica é errada, pode provocar um condição de corrida. Não tem que verificar nada, tem que inserir, se falhar é que deve tomar uma atitude.

Comment: Se o select retornar 2 ou mais registros, em qual deles é feito o update?

Comment: Desculpe, votei para fechar como "não clara o suficiente"  após observar ambiguidades e detalhes não bem informados na pergunta, expressos nos comentários.  Descreva melhor a pergunta. Descreva com clareza quais as regras do fluxo.

Comment: @DanielOmine Deu certo já, era Fazer um SELECT > INSERT ou UPDATE

Comment: @WilliamAlvares não é que deu certo, parece funcionar, é diferente. Certo é outra coisa.

Comment: ^.- Como assim, olha o código ali em baixo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua intenção com esse select para ser a de evitar registros duplicados na base dados, uma alternativa é marcar alguma coluna(email) como unique key, dessa forma um email repetido não será cadastrado.

Via  php verifique se a consulta retorna alguma coisa obtendo o registro com `fetch()`, caso tenha algo faça um update, do contrário um insert.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));

    $query = $conexao->prepare("SELECT id_mark, id_user FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id AND id_user=:idLogged");
    $query->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $coment = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($coment)){
    $insert = "UPDATE tb_comment SET comment=:comment, rate=:star, active=NOW() WHERE id_mark=:post_id AND id_user=:idLogged";
    $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
    $result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($result->execute()){
        echo 'sucesso';
    }
}else{
    $insert = "INSERT into tb_comment (id_mark, id_user, comment, up_c, down_c, rate, active) VALUES (:post_id, :idLogged, :comment, 0, 0, :star, NOW())";
    $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
    $result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if(!$result->execute()){
        echo 'error:';
    }else{
        echo 'sucesso';
    }
}
} //if
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment' cannot be null' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\pages\topic.php:215 Stack trace: #0 C:\XAMPP\htdocs\pages\topic.php(215): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\XAMPP\htdocs\page.php(28): include('C:\\XAMPP\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\pages\topic.php on line 215

Comment: @WilliamAlvares, `$comment` está vazio. No seu código não sei da onde vem

Comment: vem daqui $comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));

Comment: Consegui, vou editar seu post com o código todo aqui

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando o objeto `$result`, mas em que momento ele é instanciado? Creio que você deve utilizar o método `rowCount()` do objeto `$query`. Para mais informações sobre o método `rowCount()` veja a documentação [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Answer (score 1):

Isto resolve de forma mais simples e sem riscos de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

```
$comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));
$insert = "INSERT into tb_comment (id_mark, id_user, comment, up_c, down_c, rate, active) VALUES (:post_id, :idLogged, :comment, 0, 0, :star, NOW())";
$result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
$result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if($result->execute()){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <strong>Sucesso!</strong> avaliação cadastrada.
    </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar a avaliação.
    </div>';
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/SelectInsert.php).

Comment: Mais como vou checar se já não tem registros ?

Comment: Você precisa que seja único, certo? Então tem uma chave única configurada nesta tabela, certo? Se não tem, vai ter problemas. Com a chave única, se já existe o dado ali, o `INSERT` vai falhar. Esta é a única forma confiável de verificar se já existe. Leia o *link* na resposta. Não adianta consertar um problema e deixar os outros ativos.

Comment: Vai verificar pelo id do usuario, id_user que está logado, caso já tenha vai dar erro ou fazer o update

Comment: O que você vai fazer você decide depois, mas tem que tentar inserir do jeito certo. Ou pode fazer uma operação de *upsert* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html Não respondi sobre isto porque a pergunta não fala nada sobre.

Comment: bigown há algum topico aqui seu a respeito dessa "Condição de corrida"? Li o wiki mas sinceramente não entendi muito bem kkkk

Comment: Não, mas pode tentar achar algo em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=condição+de+corrida e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=race+condition. Este é um erro que uns 90% dos programadores cometem. Muitos mesmo aprendendo preferem não se importam porque o programa vai funcionar certa na maioria das vezes. E isto basta para a pessoa. Ela não quer o programa certo 100% das vezes.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão de correção

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $conexao->prepare("SELECT id_mark, id_user FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id AND id_user=:idLogged");
    $query->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

       if($result->rowCount() < 1){

            $comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));

            $insert = "INSERT into tb_comment (id_mark, id_user, comment, up_c, down_c, rate, active) VALUES (:post_id, :idLogged, :comment, 0, 0, :star, NOW())";

                $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
                $result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->execute();
                if($result->rowCount()){
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <strong>Sucesso!</strong> avaliação cadastrada.
                    </div>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar a avaliação.
                    </div>';
                }
        }
}
```

Removi todo esse trecho que parece não fazer sentido:

```
if($result->rowCount() >= 1){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Erro!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar sua avaliação.
    </div>';
}
if($result->rowCount() == 0){
```

e troquei por isso `if($result->rowCount() < 1){`

Troquei `if($result->rowCount() == 0){` por  `if($result->rowCount()){`

Comment: Não funcionou, não apareceu mensagem de erro e não deu erro no php e n inseriu

Comment: sério? e agora?

Comment: Nao inseriu e não deu mensagem de erro